# javafx - how to add fxml elements on run time into tab panel?

Tags: javafx

I'm using eclipse and scene builder.

I want to add elemnts on run time to tabs.
Each element is fxml file (which contains button, tableView, textbox...).

The Tab will not contain fix number of elements.

I need yours help, because I cant find a way how to do it ?
How can I add any eleemnt to tab ?
How can I add the decribed elements (fxml) into the tab ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain "add elements on run time to tabs. Each element is fxml file". As far as I know you can add just one [content](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#setContent%28javafx.scene.Node%29) in a tab. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve here ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your use case completely, but have a look at the *fx:root* construct:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

import org.drombler.commons.fx.fxml.FXMLLoaders;

public class MyCustomtPane extends BorderPane {
    public TopTestPane() throws IOException {
        loadFXML();
    }

    private void loadFXML() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoaders.loadRoot(this);
    }
}
```

In the same package add a MyCustomtPane.fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<fx:root type="BorderPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <center>
        <Label text="%label.text"/>
    </center>
</fx:root>
```

In the same package add a MyCustomtPane.properties file:

```
label.text=Some text
```

Somewhere else in your code you can use:

```
...
MyCustomtPane myCustomtPane = new MyCustomtPane(); // will load the FXML as well
addToProperPlace(myCustomtPane);
```

Note: [FXMLLoaders](http://drombler.sourceforge.net/DromblerCommons/0.4/docs/site/apidocs/org/drombler/commons/fx/fxml/FXMLLoaders.html) is a utility class I've written.
The library is Open Source and available directly from Maven Central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drombler.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>drombler-commons-fx-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.4</version>
</dependency>
```